# Android Wear: Get phone battery level for display in watch face

Tags: android, wear-os, battery

As the title says, I would like to retrieve the battery level of the phone the wearable is connected so that I can display the level on the watch face. Can someone give me a straightforward example of how to do this? I know it involves setting up a messaging system between the phone and wearable but I have no idea how to go about it.

Thanks

Comment: great idea! I'm just searching for such app. Please share it here if You found something allows get such info. I will buy such app immediately.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to implement a handset application that is gonna provide you this information.

Then, you need to make them communicate. How to do that? I would recommend you to read all of the wearable documentation, but you can make it simple using this library:

[Teleport Library for Wearable](https://github.com/Mariuxtheone/Teleport)

It provides to you everything that you need, but specifically in this case, you'll just need to use a simple sendMessage() command, after getting the info that you need from the handset device (battery status).

On the wearable side, you need to have an asynctask, also provided from this library, to receive your messages, or a service that waits for messages also. You've all the examples on the link. Good luck

Comment: I can't seem to get Teleport to work. It works on the mobile side... but I get nothing on the wear side... :-(

Comment: You've to specify the problem @DeNitE